# Get information of object in mainactivity from class

Tags: android, object, odoo

I would like to use the information of 'result' in the XMLRPCMethod. When the thread is finished the correct data is in the result object.

This is a code snipped from my OpenerpRPC.java class.

```
class XMLRPCMethod extends Thread {
        private String method;
        private Object[] params;
        private Handler handler;
        public Object result;
        private OpenerpRpc callBack;
        public XMLRPCMethod(String method, OpenerpRpc callBack) {
            this.method = method;
            this.callBack = callBack;

            handler = new Handler();
        }
        public void call() {
            call(null);
        }
        public void call(Object[] params) {;
            this.params = params;
            start();
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                result = client.callEx(method, params);
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            callBack.resultcall(result);
                        } catch (XMLRPCException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (final XMLRPCFault e) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d("Test", "error", e);
                    }
                });
            } catch (final XMLRPCException e) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Throwable couse = e.getCause();
                        if (couse instanceof HttpHostConnectException) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "error"+uri.getHost());
                        } else {
                            Log.d("Test", "error", e);
                        }
                        Log.d("Test", "error", e);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

My result call in the OpenerpRpc class looks like:

```
public void resultcall(Object result) throws XMLRPCException{

        allres=result;
        if (rtype.equals("login")){
            //Isn't impossible cast the result var with (String) because cause crash..why?
            userid=""+result;
        }

        if (rtype.equals("read")){
            //Isn't impossible cast the result var with (String) because cause crash..why?
           // userid=""+result;

        }


        // name of callback function to use in parent class (MainActivity) for receive data
        this.parent.oerpcRec(rtype,allres);

    }
```

This is how i can receive the data in mainactivity

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void oerpcRec(String rtype,Object res) throws XMLRPCException{
        if (rtype=="login"){ 

            connector.setModel("res.users");
            Object[] Ids = {Integer.parseInt(connector.userid)};
            // set here the fields you wont loads
            Object[] values={"name"};
            connector.Read(Ids,values);
        }
        if(rtype=="read"){
            Object[] ret=(Object[])res;
            Map<String, Object> map1 = (Map<String, Object>) ret[0];
            if(ret.length > 1){


            }


        }
    }
```

But how can i get this information in my mainactivity? I only get the information of the login id value. When I put a breakpoint in the thread it only goes to the function resultcall when I try to login.

...

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            //here set user and pass for login
            connector.Login(USER,PASS);

            Object[] ids = {31,30,28,26};
            Object[] params ={"partner_id","tax_line","section_id","invoice_line"};

            connector.Read(ids,params);


           //get information of openERP for specific id's

        } catch (XMLRPCException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `interface`

```
public interface MyListener {    
    public void callback(Object  result);
}
```

Your MainActivity must implement the interface

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyListener {
        ...
        ...
        ...   
        @override
        public void callback(Object result) {   
            // getting the result value.
        }
    }
```

So when your thread finish, execute the callback() method:

```
 MyListener ml;
 ml.callback(result);
```

and the `callback()` method of you `MainActivity` will receive the  object.